# How to maximize your score in this game?

Tags: game-theory

Consider the following game:

On a table, there are two glass bowls with $x$ and $y$ beads each. In each move you can do the following:

1. Remove a bead from the first bowl and put it in the second
2. Discard a bead from the second bowl

If $x+y$ is even, its your turn to move. If its odd, your opponent will move. At *each* position in the game (not just in your turns), you will get a score determined by a function $f(x, y)$

$$f(x, y) = Ax^2 + By + Cxy$$

where $A$, $B$, $C$, are constants. Your total score is the sum of your scores in all the positions during the game.

Your opponent will try to *minimize* your score. What's the maximum score you can achieve given $A, B, C, x, y$?

I have never encountered a problem with so many variables before. I have no idea how to approach it. An ideal solution would be a function $S(A, B, C, x, y)$ that would return the maximum score possible.

Comment: Are $A,B,C$ positive?

Comment: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

The way to solve this problem, for a given $A,B,C$, is to determine $S(A,B,C,x,y)$ recursively in $x$ and $y$. It's trivial to determine $S(A,B,C,0,y)$ for any $y\ge0$, since all moves must be of type $2$. From there we know that for $x>0$,
$$
S(A,B,C,x,y) = \begin{cases}
\max\{S(A,B,C,x-1,y+1),S(A,B,C,x,y-1)\}, &\text{if $x+y$ is even}, \\
\min\{S(A,B,C,x-1,y+1),S(A,B,C,x,y-1)\}, &\text{if $x+y$ is odd}. \\
\end{cases}
$$
I suggest doing explicit computations and seeing if you can detect a pattern.

Comment: How did you arrive at the recurrence relations you mentioned?

Comment: When $x+y$ is even, it's my move, and I will choose the move that maximizes the value of the game after my move. When $x+y$ is odd, my opponent will choose the move that minimizes the value of the game after her move.